# Can a Python dict item access other items of the same dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

In Python, can we define a dict with items that depend on other items of the same dict, without using dict.update() or so in more than one step?

For example:

```
d = {
     key01 : d["key02"][0],
     key02 : [1.0,2.0,3.0]
    }
```

However, this gives:

> NameError: name 'd' is not defined

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can't. The assignment to `d` can't happen until after it constructs the dictionary.

Comment: Why do you have to do it in one step?

Comment: @Barmar: You should put that as an answer.

Comment: I wonder if this is some kind of XY problem. I have a feeling he expects `key01` to contain a reference that gets updated whenever you change `key02`.

Answer (score 4):

When you are creating `d`, you expect `d` to already be created. Thus, it will not work. Instead, just reference the item earlier:

```
item = [1.0,2.0,3.0]
d = {
     key01 : item[0],
     key02 : item
    }
```